# Middle mouse button not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I recently purchased a new laptop and the middle mouse button no longer works. It is a Logitech M310 that works fine on another laptop, so I know the hardware is working. I checked the Mouse settings in the control panel and there are no settings I can change for the middle mouse button, only the wheel for scrolling. I tried updating the drivers, but they are at the latest. I am out of ideas and had no idea how much I relied on that button in Firefox.

Comment: Did you update the drivers from Logitech or with Windows from device manager?

Comment: Both. First I tried via the Device Manager, then I downloaded SetPoint from Logitech, which seemed to have no effect at all, even through it had settings I could change.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to 'Uninstall' the mouse from device manager and try to 'plugnplay' it again.

Answer (score 0):

Update the drivers of Logitech and try again also check if you have any versions to get updated.

Answer (score -1):

If the issue occurs only in the browser, then it may be a problematic extension/addon interfering (try disabling them).

If it happens in every application, install setpoint app from Logitech. There's also a setpoint extension for Chrome which can help.

Answer (score -1):

For a Logitech mouse that is not working in the browser, install the SetPoint extension into Chrome and Firefox to get scrolling to work properly. That may fix your problem. If not, there may be some problematic extension present in your browser, so disable all the extension in your browser.